# Why the property value passed to differed execution custom action are always blank?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I am paasing MSI property to my custom action DLL which is a differed execution custom action, but it is always blank...

i am not getting the reason...

how can i solve this?

Comment: You should read http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deferred custom actions do not have access to public properties, except a couple of special ones, like "CustomActionData".

You can use an immediate custom action to set special property "CustomActionData" with the value of your property, and then from your deferred custom action read the value of "CustomActionData" instead of your property.